# "From which to" how should I interpret this?

Tags: grammar, determiners, connotations

The full sentence is this:

> Instead of creating a mathematical model from which to predict performance, the workload can be characterized, simulated, and then tested on clouds of different scales.

Where I'm stuck now is here `P from which to V`. I think I understand what it means somehow though, I wonder why there is *which* for what. What's the difference with "Instead of creating a mathematical model from predicting performance, ..."?

[someone asked like this before](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/561555/is-it-correct-to-say-in-which-to-from-which-to-on-which-to-etc), and they said it's *to infinitive*, so I tried to understand it as "creating ... from which (to ...)" now it's more clear than before to me. but still I wonder what's the difference with "creating ... from (to ...)"

Comment: 'Instead of creating a mathematical model from which to predict performance,' = 'Instead of creating a mathematical model which can be used to predict performance,' = 'Instead of creating a mathematical model from which we will be able to predict performance,'.  Compare the simpler 'This is a base from which to explore Devon' = 'This is a base from which one / we / you / they can explore Devon'.

Comment: Compare "Building a house in which I will live..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This construction is related to the old “never end a sentence with a preposition”
The original could be phrased

> … creating a model to predict performance from.

To avoid that it is inverted with the help of a pronoun.

> … creating a model from which to predict performance.

Comment: In writing, from which, of which etc. is very common.

Comment: Yep. ‘Cuz writing is a format formality is observed in.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the clause to "from which [model] one can predict performance", it should make the grammar a little less opaque.

In English, relative clauses can be headed by an infinitive instead of a finite verb. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_relative_clauses, in the section called Nonfinite Relative Clauses.